# pagination with filter in vueJs

Tags: jquery, pagination, vue.js, vue-resource

I have found code [in here](https://jsfiddle.net/xakvbzur/8/)

```
v-for="rowinvitation in viewListInvitation | sourceInvitation | limitBy count offset"
```

but I found error, when I click last page & I find in page one, he is error.

for ex: I have click page 9 in pagination & I find "Kathy". in paginate displaying -3,-2-1,0 & nothing result,

How I can find "Kathy" when condition in last page "9"

Comment: First, start to use sentences, capitals, and generally improve your grammar. Your undecipherable quedtion looks as if you would be a 7 yr old little boy. If your grammar improves, you will be able to ask questions on the internet, which people understands and so they will be able to help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your items has changed; in this case, becoming less.

You'll should watch for items changes, and call the update method to reset the active page parameter, so we can jump back to first page.

Add the below codes in your paging component and it should do the trick:

```
        watch: {
            'items': function(){
                this.update(0);
            }
        },
```